# problems writing sql and insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert, user-profile

I am trying to write an `insert` statement where the job is to take selected item the user has selected then insert it into their profile.

I am using Profile provider.

There is a new column I have made in `UserProfile` table (that stores stuff like username, age and so forth) and I have called it `Rented`.

e.g.:

- User `Tom45`
- rented `Pirates of The caribbean`
- age `23`

Could someone let me know if I am doing it right as I can't seem to get it to work.

My Insert and SQL:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNetDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    {
        da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Rented) VALUES (@Rented) WHERE [UserName] = ?", conn);
        string dvdrent = DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        OleDbParameter rented = new OleDbParameter();
        {
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rented", DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
        }
        conn.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have this table:

[image]

And each user has a profile:

[image]

Once they're logged in they can choose to rent dvds:

[image]

The problem is I do not think my query does this, as it does not work.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement is invalid: you aren't specifying values to insert (the `VALUES` portion of an `INSERT` statement).

Comment: Insert where or update where?

Comment: It is not a duplicate due to the other was asking a different question, is one i am asking if the way i am writing the statement is correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. instead @Render write question mark.
2. you need add second parameter for the User criteria, and set it.

so:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNetDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    {
        da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Rented) VALUES (?) WHERE [UserName] = ? ;", conn);

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rented", DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", XXXXXXXXX);

        conn.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: when I try this I get this error,  Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.

Comment: Still getting error {"Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."}

Comment: place a break point in ExecuteNonQuery row and debug. when app is stoped put in immediate window this:  `? da.InsertCommand.CommandText`. What is the resul?

Comment: I can run a break point but what do you mean by when app is stopped